# How do I use Windows.Open to open a new web page right above my website while dulling out the background

Tags: javascript, css

I need to open a new web page (on another site) right above my existing website while dulling out the background. I'm trying to make it look like this new web page is part of the original website. Something that Peek.com does here: http://www.thrillermiami.com/rates.html

```
(function(idPrefix) {
    id = idPrefix + '-js';
    if (document.getElementById(id)) return;
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    el = document.createElement('script');
    window.peekButton = '<img data-activity-gid="51636864f42dc1000200018c" data-ticket-gid="51636865f42dc100020001a6" name="Image12" width="348" height="78" border="0" src="images/make_r.jpg" />';
    el.id = id;
    var date = new Date;
    var stamp = date.getMonth() + "-" + date.getDate();
    el.src = "https://pirassets.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/widget_button.js?id=51636864f42dc10002000186&ts=" + stamp;
    head.appendChild(el);
    id = idPrefix + '-css';
    el = document.createElement('link');
    el.id = id;
    el.href = "https://pirassets.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/widget_button.css?id=51636864f42dc10002000186&ts=" + stamp;
    el.rel = "stylesheet";
    el.type = "text/css";
    head.appendChild(el);
}('peek-booking-button'));
```

Comment: Do you mean opening another website in a iframe inside your website ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code doesn't make a lot of sense, but I think you can try
setting the css to dim on any the iframe click?

```
.dim{
//make your chosen dim
}

    $('.link').click(function(){
        $('.dim').fadeIn(200);
    },function(){
        $('.dim').fadeOut(200);
    });
```